# R: invalid argument to unary operator - trying to sort data using order()

Tags: r

Im getting an error when trying to sort my data frame by the model_AIC column

example of data
[image]

```
data <- structure(list(model_ID = list(model_table = character(0), model_info_2 = "S_M ~ 1 + average_Ca_LOG + (1 + average_Ca_LOG | ID)", 
                               model_info_2 = "S_M ~ 1 + average_Mg_LOG + (1 + average_Mg_LOG | ID)", 
                               model_info_2 = "S_M ~ 1 + average_K_LOG + (1 + average_K_LOG | ID)", 
                               model_info_2 = "S_M ~ 1 + average_Mn_LOG + (1 + average_Mn_LOG | ID)", 
                               model_info_2 = "S_M ~ 1 + average_Cu_LOG + (1 + average_Cu_LOG | ID)", 
                               model_info_2 = "S_M ~ 1 + average_Zn_LOG + (1 + average_Zn_LOG | ID)"), 
               model_AIC = list(model_table = numeric(0), model_info_2 = "1504.62", 
                                model_info_2 = "1636.35", model_info_2 = "1620", model_info_2 = "1407.41", 
                                model_info_2 = "1855.04", model_info_2 = "1706.71"), 
               model_BIC = list(model_table = numeric(0), model_info_2 = "1531.06251699724", 
                                model_info_2 = "1662.78856677628", model_info_2 = "1646.44040865957", 
                                model_info_2 = "1433.85260732148", model_info_2 = "1881.47787878473", 
                                model_info_2 = "1733.15601219833")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("model_table", 
                                                                                                         "model_info_2", "model_info_2.1", "model_info_2.2", "model_info_2.3", 
                                                                                                         "model_info_2.4", "model_info_2.5"))


data[order(-data$model_AIC),][1:5,]
```

error
Error in -data$model_AIC : invalid argument to unary operator

Comment: Try `data[c(1, order(-as.numeric(unlist(data$model_AIC[-1]))) + 1), ]`.

Comment: @jay.sf that works great, thank you! Is there a way to do it in ascending order as well?

Comment: Try to understand the code, then remove the minus in `order()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with tidyverse. The code will be easier to read.
For example

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>%
  mutate(model_AIC_int = as.integer(model_AIC)) %>%
  arrange(desc(model_AIC_int))

# or just
data %>%
  arrange(desc(as.integer(model_AIC)))
```